# How to dynamically generate css class inside an each statement for an Ember View

Tags: dynamic, ember.js, each

```
  <div>
  {{#each value in controller}}
  <div {{classNameBindings "col-lg-{{value}}"}}>{{value}}</div>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
```

Above is my partial view.

I want to generate classes like: col-lg-1, col-lg-2 etc
My controller is:

```
App.circleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('content', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
    }
});
```

why I get error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. ?

Comment: Do you need to have class binding? Or just generate the class names?

Comment: I'm sure there is away to use nth-child CSS selector to put the right classes on the right elements. If you gave me a bit more info of what you want the final project should look like, I point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom view to apply dynamically-named classes to items inside of an `each` helper. The class name is generated inside the view by a property than depends on a supplied index.

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['itemClass'],
    index: null,

    itemClass: function() {
        return 'class-'+this.get('index');
    }.property('index')
});
```

In the template, I supply the index through a `{{view}}` helper inside each iteration.

```
{{#each value in controller}}
    {{#view App.ItemView indexBinding="value"}}
        Item #{{value}}
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

For a closer look, [check out this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/w7UCd/).